# How to integrate a django project with the zinnia app after installing it?

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I downloaded Zinnia from https://www.djangopackages.com/python3/. and successfully installed it in my WIN8 OS.C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django_blog_zinnia-0.14.dev-py3.3.egg\zinnia.

I have a django project -- 'C:\Users\Nan\iwebs'. and now I want to make zinnia its app.

But the website says nothing about what to do next.

Should I copy the dictionary `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django_blog_zinnia-0.14.dev-py3.3.egg\zinnia` to `C:\Users\Nan\iwebs`, and modify INSTALLED_APPS in C:\Users\Nan\iwebs\mysite\settings.py and urls.py?

If I should, it still doesn't work becuase after doing this, I attempted to run `python manage.py syncdb`, it says no module named 'mptt'.

If I shouldn't, what should I do?

Or where is the related tutorial to tell people how to make zinnia a project's app?

I am really tired after searching for solutions for nearly 4 hours, any help will be apreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "installation" section of zinnia's doc clearly states the dependencies - including mptt - and how to add zinnia to your project.

Comment: thank you! maybe I was too tired. http://django-blog-zinnia.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9/install.html#dependencies.